# How can I bulk edit wp_metadata for multiple posts?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I've made a bunch of posts on my installation with some custom fields (supplied by theme).
I've named one of these fields "Telefon" with values like "444 44 444", however I would like to change the values to a `"<p><a href="tel:+47 444 44 444">444 44 444</a></p>"`

I've looked in PHPMyAdmin, but I've got no idea how to accomplish my task, because of field length...

What I've got:

```
s:8:"Telefon:";i:1;s:10:"415 70 766";
```

What I'd like:

```
s:8:"Telefon:";i:1;s:50:"<p><a href="tel:+47 415 70 766">415 70 766</a></p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a temporary function inside your functions.php to bulk edit all fields.

```
function tempUpdate() {
   global $wpdb;
   return $wpdb->update($wpdb->postmeta, [‘meta_value’ => [‘Telefon’ => ‘your string here’]], [‘meta_key’ => ‘your field name’]);

}
var_dump(tempUpdate());
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But it wont solve my problem...
I have 200 different values that I want to change... (Phonenumbers that I would like to make clickable)

Comment: Maybe I could help, can you please reconsider your question. And maybe add more details to it.

Comment: OK. What I'm after is changing some metavalue in LOTS of posts...
What I've got is a metavalue in my database like this: ´s:8:"Telefon:";i:1;s:10:"123 45 678";´ I would however like it to be ´s:8:"Telefon:";i:1;s:10:"<a href="tel:123 45 678">123 45 678</a>";´
In other words I'd like to make the current number a phone-hyperlink.

Comment: And did you try my code? Or what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your code wont let me "reuse" the metavalue already in the database. I want to change the value, not replace it. There are about 200 different posts, all with different metavalue...

Comment: So you want to change the value on save each time?

Comment: No, I would like to do this one time for everything I've already entered. For the future I'll do it the "right" way :)